# Is there boost::visit like std::visit, for boost::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-variant, std-variant

With C++14, I'm using `boost::variant` as a way of compile-time polymorphism:

```
using MyType = boost::variant<A, B>;
```

Both classes have a method `sayHello()`. I'd like to call:

```
MyType obj = ...; // either A() or B()
boost::visit([](auto&& o) { o.sayHello();}, obj);
```

I know the [`static_visitor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/variant.html) way, but I find it cumbersome. Is there a `boost::visit` like [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) that I'm missing? If not, why doesn't it exist?

Minimal example [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/267ff0764c36f03d).

Comment: Have you tried using lambda instead of static visitor in apply_visitor? IRC, it should "just work"(tm).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is, but it's called [`boost::apply_visitor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html). Its behavior in relation to `boost::variant` is the as `std::visit`'s to `std::variant`.